# How can I set a text as a label instead of opening a new page?

Tags: php, html

I am using a newsletter script from a predefined solution:

```
<?php

# SUBJECT
$subject = '';
if (isset($_POST['s1'])) $subject = $_POST['s1'];
if ($subject=='')
{
$subject='Remove';
}
else
{
$subject='Subscribe';
}

# LIST EMAIL ADDRESS
$recipient = 'email@domain.com';

# VERIFY SYNTAX
if(!preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9.-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9]\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/i', $_POST['f16']))
{
die ('Please enter a valid email.');
}

# FORM VALUES
$body = '';
$body .= "Email: ".$_POST['f16']." \n";

# SEND MESSGAE
mail( $recipient, $subject, $body, "From: $recipient") or die ('Error message');

# SHOW RESULT PAGE
header('Location: http://google.com');
?>
```

How can I display a label underneath my input instead of opening a new window?

Comment: Is there any more code that you could share and more details about what you're trying to do?

Comment: What do you mean by displaying a label? What does that have to do with the above mail-script and opening new windows? Are you asking about sending the email and show the result on the same page without reloading?

Comment: @Craig is right. We don't really know exactly what you've tried. And as with ANY programming language, context is a b&*ch. Can you be more specific in your question?

Comment: preassign a variable to it and echo it inside the label, *n'est-ce pas?* I can't see how it couldn't be done; have you tried anything? why a label though?

Comment: Updated the code. I want to display the "Error message" in a label on my form page, maybe like this: `<?php echo $result; ?>`

Comment: And to be honest, my php is horrible so I don't know how I could adapt it.

Comment: you'd need to use a ternary operator then http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php; it's better for stuff like that. But that would mean using the form and php together in the same file. Otherwise, you'd need to use js/ajax; you have a choice.

Comment: You should really use PHP's built in [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) when validating e-mail addresses. It's not as trivial as people think and most regex's out there do miss a lot of special cases..

Comment: It is for a Wordpress file so I can also use it in the same file

Comment: [this comment I left...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39778148/how-can-i-set-a-text-as-a-label-instead-of-opening-a-new-page#comment66850846_39778148) is what the answer is to this, without writing code out in an answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- how could this be solved with js or ajax?